# How to instantiate an inherited class without calling base default constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

just curious. I have a custom asp.net identity user store class that inherits IdentityUser class. It is defined this way:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {

    }
}
```

Notice I am not calling base constructor explicitly.

I know that even when I am not calling the base constructor explicitly, it is called implicitly.

I demonstrated that when debugging it. When I just enter ApplicationUser constructor, `Id` member of base class   contains already a value equal to some GUID string.

That comes from base class constructor I saw using reflection:

```
public IdentityUser()
{
  this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

Is there some workaround on this?

In my custom user store, ID is an integer primary key, but I am setting it with the value from database at a later stage, so it doesn't matter if that GUID is assigned to that member as default, but I am wondering if that can be avoided. Maybe by inheriting from the other classes and implementing other interface: `IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUser, IUser<string>` replacing `string` by `int`.

Any comments about this?

Regards

Jaime

Comment: "Is there some workaround on this?" - no, that's part of the language design. I don't really understand your final sentence, but basically you should design your code so that it doesn't try to fight against the language rules.

Comment: @JonSkeet the fact is that, by design, EF identity is creating the user with an ID to be a GUID by default, it is not precisely a language rule. That is, Microsoft is assuming all people in the world will be using primary keys to be GUID's, which is wrong.

Comment: Of course you can change the PK type if you want, but I'd prefer another direction. I'd leave the ASP.Net identity model unaltered and only refer to it from your application code. I.e. `ApplicationUser` doesn't inherit from `IdentityUser` but knows its PK value. That'll make it much easier to use a separate IdentityDbContext and a business-related context (or more) and prevent mixing concerns.

Comment: I am using a custom identity model, other database tables, more simplified and not all that useless tables microsoft uses. All my site security works like a charm, and I prefer the PK to be an autoincremented number so I don't worry about its generation and since it is an integer, it is faster to access and to be searched. This question was only a curiosity. It does not annoy me but I wonder why Microsoft, who really designs extensible components and libraries, assumes all people in the universe to use a GUID in the PK.  A better design should be to allow developer to decide if use it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do something hacky.
I approve; here you go.

```cs
var user = (ApplicationUser)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(ApplicationUser));
```